# Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found

Tags: pom.xml, junit4, allure, autotest

after running the tests i use the command: allure surve.
but i am catching the exception: "Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found."

All stack:

```
 C:\Users\maxim\.jdks\openjdk-18.0.2.1\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\maxim\IdeaProjects\test\2 -Djansi.passthrough=true "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=54887:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2023.1.2 io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:2.9:serve
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< test:test-autotest >-------------------
[INFO]                   Building test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- allure-maven:2.9:serve (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\maxim\IdeaProjects\test/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.0.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report (serve) with version 2.0.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\maxim\IdeaProjects\test\2\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[ERROR] Directory C:\Users\maxim\IdeaProjects\test\2\target\allure-results not found.
[WARNING] Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.091 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-07T14:03:08+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I used these totorials:

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/JUnit

https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_junit_4

What am I doing wrong?

POM:
https://gist.github.com/vindus940/bb90e8e377f5c1c6ee4b3965a522ddd7